# Setting timeout for custom service (chkconfig)

Tags: linux, redhat, systemctl

I wrote a custom script that I want to be executed each time my server starts and stops. I added the script with chkconfig:

```
chkconfig --add myservice
```

This is working fine. But from time to time I run into timeout. I check the systemctl settings and I can see the timeout is set to 5 min:

```
systemctl show myservice.service | grep Timeout
TimeoutStartUSec=5min
TimeoutStopUSec=5min
JobTimeoutUSec=0
JobTimeoutAction=none
```

So I assumed I need to create a file with service settings under /etc/systemd/system, but each time I do that, my service is not executing at all and disappears from chkconfig --list.

When I run systemctl list-unit-files, in addition, I can see my service status is set to masked. But when I delete the file from /etc/systemd/system everything is back to normal.

Could anyone explain me how can I customize the startup for my service?

Best regards
Fr.

Comment: I suggest you to move this post to <a href="https://unix.stackexchange.com">Unix&Linux</a> this site.

Comment: Did you run "systemctl daemon-reload" after adding your service?  Also, if this a bespoke service, I would add it under /etc/init.d for the old SysVInit configuration or under /usr/lib/systemd/system for the new systemd configuration

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, I tried to reload systemctl, but it doesn't have any effect on my service. It's still marked as masked.
The service itself is saved under /etc/init.d. 
I tried to put the service configuration file under /usr/lib/systemd, but I run into the exact same issue.

Comment: If the service is masked, why not run "systemctl unmask servicename"

Comment: I tried, but no effect :( the service is still shown as masked. I also tried to reload systemctl afterwards.